# Jquery second button cannot fire

Tags: jquery

I got two button as below:

```
<input id="btn_sendmsg" name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE 1" />
<input id="btn_sendmsg" name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE 2" />
```

when I click `"SEND MESSAGE 1"` button, it works and fire properly, but the `"SEND MESSAGE 2"` button doesn't fire at all, what's the issue?

```
$("#btn_sendmsg").live('click', function(){
    parameters = $('#form1').serialize();
    alert(parameters);
});
```

Thanks.

Comment: `.live()` was deprecated in jQuery 1.7, and removed in 1.9. Use `.on` or `.click`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ID of an element](http://www.w3.org/TR/2011/WD-html5-20110525/elements.html#the-id-attribute) should be unique in a document, use a class instead if you want to associate same key to multiple elements.

If there are multiple elements with the same id then the [id-selector](http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/) will always return only the first element with the id

```
<input class="btn_sendmsg" name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE 1" />
<input class="btn_sendmsg" name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE 2" />
```

then

```
$(".btn_sendmsg").live('click', function(){
    parameters = $('#form1').serialize();
    alert(parameters);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have both buttons with the same id. Change the id to 2 different names or make then part of the same class.

**Different ID's**

```
<input id="btn_sendmsg1" name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE 1" />
<input id="btn_sendmsg2" name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE 2" />

//Add a click handler for each id
$("#btn_sendmsg1").live('click', function(){
    parameters = $('#form1').serialize();
    alert(parameters);
});

$("#btn_sendmsg2").live('click', function(){
    parameters = $('#form1').serialize();
    alert(parameters);
});
```

**Same class**

```
<input id="btn_sendmsg1" name="send_message" type="button" class="btn" value="SEND MESSAGE 1" />
<input id="btn_sendmsg2" name="send_message" type="button" class="btn" value="SEND MESSAGE 2" />

//This click handler is attached to the class
$(".btn").live('click', function(){
    parameters = $('#form1').serialize();
    alert(parameters);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input class="btn_sendMsg name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE 1" />
<input class="btn_sendMsg name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE 2" />

$('input.btn_sendMsg').click(function(){
      //code here         
});
```

Use `$(this)` to get the element that was clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't assign a same id for difference element. Instead of, you can assign to it by class.

```
<input class="btn_sendmsg" name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE 1" />
<input class="btn_sendmsg" name="send_message" type="button" value="SEND MESSAGE 2" />
```

And try to use looping operator in jquery to assign any event to it.

```
$(".btn_sendmsg").each(function(){
    $(this).live('click',function(){
       parameters = $('#form1').serialize();
       alert(parameters);
    });
});
```